# How to re-assign value to a dictionary based on

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to implement a function on a dictionary.

Variables:

- The existing dictionary has the letters I have to play and the value represent the frequency of the letter.  eg. `{'a': 1, 'n': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1}`
- The word represent a word constructed with those letters. eg. `'and'`

I need to implement a code which return a dictionary with all letters remaining (that are not in the word) and their values(frequency). Value should be zero if the letter was used.

I have wrote this code:

```py
dic = {'a': 1, 'n': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1} 
word = 'and'

newdic = {}
for keys in dic:
    if keys not in word:
        newdic[keys] = newdic.get(keys,0) + 1
print(newdic)
```

the output I got is: `{'e': 1}`
but the Expected output should be:  `{'a': 0, 'n': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 1}`
can you please advise? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic = {'a': 1, 'n': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1} 
word = 'and'

newdic = {}
for keys in dic:
    if keys not in word:
        newdic[keys] = newdic.get(keys, 0) + 1
    else:
        newdic[keys] = dic.get(keys, 0) -1 
print(newdic)
```

I think this is what you were looking for. See the for-loop statement and the `else` part added.

Answer (score 1):

This can help. Add an `else`statement for the `keys` that are in the word [in this case, `"and"`].

```
dic = {'a': 1, 'n': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1} 
word = 'and'

newdic = {}
for keys in dic.keys():
    if keys not in word:
        newdic[keys] = dic[keys]+1
    else:
        newdic[keys] = dic[keys]-1
print(newdic)
```